# Quiero cambiar una imagen segun el option selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un `<select>` con varios `option values`:

```
<select name="fld_4447635" value="" data-field="fld_4447635" class="form-control" id="fld_4447635_1" aria-labelledby="fld_4447635Label">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Locations</option>
  <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
  <option>Paris</option>
</selected>
```

Y al lado tengo una imagen con `src`. Me gustaría que según el valor que coja de `option` con `jQuery`, la imagen que cambie su `src`.

He intentado esto pero no funciona:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

     $('#madrid').click(function(){
        $('.responsive-image-header').replaceWith('<img id="cambio" src="http://localhost/evualahopruebas/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/room-3.jpg" alt="imagen cambiada" width="500" height="400">');
     });

});
```

Si me pudierais ayudar os lo agradecería.

Comment: puedes añadir el html?

Comment: Por favor lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), puesto que tu `html` no corresponde al `jquery` y no es correcto.

Answer (score 2):

Como valor de las opciones necesitas utilizar el nombre de la imagen. Al cambiar el elemento seleccionado recuperas el valor y lo utilizas para construir el valor del atributo src de la imagen.

```js
elSelect.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  laImagen.setAttribute("src","https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/" + elSelect.selectedOptions[0].value + ".jpg")
})
```

```html
<img id="laImagen" width="100" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" />

<select id="elSelect">
  <option value="">Seleccione algo</option>
  <option value="butterfly">Madrid</option>
  <option value="enfeinada250">Paris</option>
</select>
```

Este ejemplo es muy básico. En practica quieres primero verificar si las imágenes están ya cargadas antes de empezar a cambiarlas.